# How do I save Excel Workbook after running macro with Python?

Tags: python, excel

The code for python works except that once it has ran I still get a box from excel asking "want to save your changes to workbook" what I seem to be missing in my code is to add something that will SAVE the workbook at the very end. I use RTD functions in the workbook which might be the reason the popup.

This is my python code used.

```
from __future__ import print_function
import unittest
import os.path
import win32com.client

class ExcelMacro(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_excel_macro(self):
        try:
            xlApp = win32com.client.DispatchEx('Excel.Application')
            xlsPath = os.path.expanduser('C:\Magic Samsung\Watch Samsung\Workbook.xlsm')
            wb = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(Filename=xlsPath)
            xlApp.Run('ArchiveMaster')
            wb.Save()
            xlApp.Quit()
            print("Macro ran successfully!")
        except:
            print("Error found while running the excel macro!")
            xlApp.Quit()
            if __name__ == "__main__":
            unittest.main()
```

Comment: did you try saving it as macro enabled ..with .xlsm extension

Comment: yes I have saved it as macro enabled.

Comment: Below code is working @Try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

according to this [Link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/xlfileformat-enumeration-excel)  `xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled` is 52. so, while saving just give the argument FileFormat = 52 as shown in the below code

```
class ExcelMacro(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_excel_macro(self):
        try:
            xlApp = win32com.client.DispatchEx('Excel.Application')
            xlapp.DisplayAlerts=False
            xlsPath = os.path.expanduser('C:\Magic Samsung\Watch Samsung\Workbook.xlsm')
            wb = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(Filename=xlsPath)
            xlApp.Run('ArchiveMaster')
            wb.SaveAs(Filename=path_here, FileFormat=52)
            xlApp.Quit()
            print("Macro ran successfully!")
        except:
            print("Error found while running the excel macro!")
            xlApp.Quit()
            if __name__ == "__main__":
            unittest.main()
```

Note: A pop-up appear's while using saveAs. This [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17674867/how-to-disable-the-save-as-prompt) and [This So 
 Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3373955/python-and-excel-overwriting-an-existing-file-always-prompts-despite-xlsavecon) answer's this problem

Comment: It does run but at the end I still get the excel popup "want to save your changes to workbook" which I just want to save....

Comment: @Try, check the answer, i have updated it with a solution, in short, do wb.DisplayAlerts = False

Comment: at what point in the code would I add wb.DisplayAlerts = False?

Comment: Try Before saving

Comment: Still getting excel popup "want to save your changes to workbook" :(

Comment: try with xlapp.DisplayAlerts=False

Comment: just can't seem to finish off the code for the excel popup "want to save your changes to workbook"

Comment: i am trying it now, i will update the code in another 15 minutes

Comment: @Try, i just did, and i did not get any pop-up

Comment: The new updated one unfortunately didn't run at all. The issue is that the file is saved then application quit but I use an RTD function in excel that updates data in 2 mins intervals so when Python quits excel you get the prompt of either (save, don't save, cancel) somehow I need a code to choose save at this stage.